# Is it efficient to use two sqlite databases on unity project?

Tags: c#, sqlite, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to develop a unity game app that focus on spelling the word.

I have words database `word_db` and a separate players information database `Player_db`. In the registration of new player I'm getting id of the word from `word_db` in random order and insert it into `player_db`. But it seems to need too much time to complete the task. Is there any way to make it faster or is it advisable to merge two databases?

The `word_db` contains thousands of words and its definition.

Comment: No. Not a good design. Should be the same database.

Comment: @HristoYankov  thanks for your reply. I'll now restructure my db. :)

Comment: Thousands is a small number. Unless you can REALLY justify it, in 99% cases it's better (and easier) to use just a single database. If you could justify it, you probably wouldn't asking here about it :)

Answer (score 0):

The main issue with SQLite with Unity3D is you're likely retaining a separate instance of SQLite than the ones native to the OS (unless you are writing your own native implementations). As such your writes/reads aren't as balanced and more over the time it takes to do both at the same time essentially queues (which depending on your read/write lock implementations as well).

We found SQLite to be a pig on devices and given we're not inclined to write iOS/Android/Microsoft flavoured specific versions we instead opted for [SiaqoDB](http://siaqodb.com/) instead (which uses LightingDB). There's some minor heavy lifting when it comes to setup but in the end, we found that partitioning and/or hot swapping Databases based on user credentials to be more efficient (1000's time faster).

We store around 300million+ records in some cases just in one "table".